# Inclusion of classical spaces in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

**Context:** Today I was introduced to a very nice diagram where we can see the relation between several spaces in analysis. It goes as follows: $$\text{Hilbert Sp.} \subset \text{Inner Prod. Sp.} \subset \text{Normed. Sp.} \subset \text{Metric Sp.} \subset \text{Topological Sp.}$$

What I am trying to do is to find examples for each case:

**$\text{Metric Sp.} \subset \text{Topological Sp.}$**: We know that in the topology induced by the metric, the open sets are the open balls. However, I am wondering if there's any *proposition*, as in the next two cases, that can in some way describe the topologies that can be induced by a metric.

**$\text{Normed. Sp.} \subset \text{Metric Sp.}$**: It is easy to find examples for metric spaces that are not normed spaces by checking if the metric satisfies *homogeneity* and if it is *translation invariant*. **Example:** In the space of sequences, consider the metric $d(x,y) = \sum_{I=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^I}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}$.

**$\text{Inner Prod. Sp.} \subset \text{Normed. Sp.}$**: For this case we have the *Parallelogram Law* to see if a norm can be induced by an inner product. **Example:** the space $l^p$ with norm $||\cdot||_p$ with $p \neq 2$, cannot be induced by an inner product. Thus $l^p$ is a normed space that's not an inner product space.

**$\text{Hilbert Sp.} \subset \text{Inner Prod. Sp.}$**: We need to find a space that is not complete for the metric induced by the norm, and the norm induced by the inner product. Clearly, every inner product space that cannot induce a metric won't be complete, thus not a Hilbert space. However, I am looking for a case where we can induce a metric, but the space with this metric is not complete.

**TLDR**: Need an example of a topological space that's not a metric space; And another example of an inner product space that's not an Hilbert space (accepting only those cases where we can induce the metric from the norm and the norm from inner product)

Thank you.

Comment: For a topological space that is not metrizable, use a non-Hausdorff space, like an infinite set with the cofinite topology (the nonempty open sets are the complements of finite sets).

Comment: For an inner product space that is not a Hilbert space, use any dense proper subspace of a Hilbert space, like $\mathbf Q^n$ inside $\mathbf R^n$ with the usual inner product on $n$-tuples or $C[0,1]$ with the $L^2$-norm (it is dense in its $L^2$-completion $L^2[0,1]$).

Comment: For a non-complete inner-product space, take the subspace of $\ell^2$ consisting in sequences which have only a finite number of non-zero terms.

Comment: @KCd I think your second example is better because $\Bbb Q^n$ is not an $\Bbb R$-vector space.

Comment: A metric space $X$ is a $T_1$ space. That is, if $p\in X$ then $\{p\}$ is a closed set. Sierpinskt space is $S=\{0,1\}$ where $\emptyset, S,$ and $\{0\}$ are open sets but $\{1\}$ is $not$ open, so $\{0\}$ is not closed, so $S$ is not metrizable.